# Tkinter frame sizes when using class and raise()

Tags: python, tkinter, grid, frames

Hi All can anyone help me figure out how to make each of the frames 600x400. Individually as frames if I added them to the window they would work but using this method to raise frames has got me stumped.

[image: This is the launch screen]

[image: This is when I click on the login button]

The frames sizes are set by their content.

Any help greatly appreciated. Also, I do not want to use Pack I prefer working with grid.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font as tkfont  # python 3
from PIL import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from PIL import ImageTk ,Image



class InterimMain(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # Gets the requested values of the height and widht.
        windowWidth = 600
        windowHeight = 400


        # Gets both half the screen width/height and window width/height
        positionRight = int(self.winfo_screenwidth()/2 - windowWidth/2)
        positionDown = int(self.winfo_screenheight()/2 - windowHeight)

        # Positions the window in the center of the page.
        self.geometry("{}x{}+{}+{}".format(800,600,positionRight, positionDown))

        #self.attributes('-alpha', 0.5)
        
        
        container = tk.Frame(self,width=600, height= 400)
        container.config(background="red")
                        
        container.place(relx = 0.5,rely=0.5,anchor='c')
        #w = WelcomeScreen(controller)
        #l =Login(controller)
        
        
        self.frames = {}
        
        for F in (WelcomeScreen, Login):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.place(relx = 0.5,rely=0.5,anchor='c')
       
        self.show_frame("WelcomeScreen")

    
    
    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()

    

class WelcomeScreen(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,width=600, height=400)
        
        Label(self,text="WELCOME TO THE INTRIM REPORT",font=("Arial Bold",16))\
                            .grid(row=0, pady=20)
        load = Image.open("logo2.jpg")
        render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
        
        # labels can be text or images
        img = Label(self, image=render)
        
        img.image = render
        
        img.grid(row=1)
        
        Label(self,text="Press the button to proceed",font=("Arial Bold",10))\
                                .grid(padx=5,row=2,pady=10)
        Button = tk.Button(self,text="Sign In",font=("Arial Bold",16),command=lambda: controller.show_frame("Login"))
        Button.grid(row=3,padx=20,pady=20)
        

class Login(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,width=600, height=400)
        
        self.config(background="blue")

       

        Label(self,text="LOGIN SCREEN",font=("Arial Bold",16))\
                            .grid(row=0,column=0,pady=10,columnspan=3)
        

        Label(self,text="Username",font=("Arial",12)).grid(row=1,column=0,sticky='w')
        Label(self,text="Password",font=("Arial",12)).grid(row=2,column=0,sticky='w')
        user = Entry(self)
        pwd = Entry(self)
        user.grid(row=1,column=1,pady=5,columnspan=2,sticky='we')
        pwd.grid(row=2,column=1,pady=5,columnspan=2,sticky='we')
        
        
        Button = tk.Button(self,text="LOGIN",command=lambda:checkLogin(str(user.get()),str(pwd.get())))
        Button.grid(row=3,column=2,columnspan=3,sticky='e')




if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = InterimMain()
    app.mainloop()
#login.place(relx = 0.5,rely=0.4,anchor='c')
'''
```

Comment: I am not entirely sure as I am new to tkinter however maybe ```.geometry()``` would work?

Comment: Hi thanks no tried .geometry() but thank you. Geometry is only for the actual window and not the frames.

Comment: Oh Ok. Well good luck anyway on finding an answer. Someone with more knowledge on tkinter will stop by :D

Comment: Since `place()` is used, you can specify the width and height: `frame.place(relx = 0.5,rely=0.5,relwidth=1,relheight=1anchor='c')`.

Comment: Thank you works but now places all of my widgets in the top left hand corner?

Comment: It is because `WelcomeScreen` and `Login` frames are children of root, not `container`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the grid geometry manager only, you'll face the problem that the standard behavior for a frame with widgets inside of it is to resize itself to the smaller size possible, yet enough to contain its children (labels, buttons, entries, etc).

In such case you will not know in advance the dimensions of the controlled frames and the use of `tkraise()` will not work, since one controlled frame might be bigger than the other controlled frame and will still be visible when the smaller frame is raised.

I could find 2 solutions to this:

One solution is to force all controlled frames to have a fixed size and not resize themselves when you add widgets to them with the grid manager.
tkraise() can then be used to selectively show a controlled frame (since all controlled frames have the same fixed dimensions, bringing one to the front will hide the others).
`.grid_propagate()`is needed here

> **w.grid_propagate()**
> Normally, all widgets propagate their dimensions, meaning that they adjust to fit the contents.
> However, sometimes you want to force a widget to be a certain size, regardless of the size of its
> contents. To do this, call w.grid_propagate(0) where w is the widget whose size you want to
> force.

The down side is that it will be harder to organize the children widgets in a fixed size frame in order to get the appearance you deisre. You might have to carefully play with `padx` and `pady`
(By the way, you can use `padx=(left, right)` to specify different padding for the lef hand side and the right hand side of a widget. The same applies to pady, as `pady=(top, bottom)`

The code below uses this solution of fixed size frames (`.grid_propagate(0)`) and `tkraise()`
Note: I'm usig Python 3.9.1

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font as tkfont  # python 3
from tkinter.ttk import *

class InterimMain(tk.Tk):

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    # Requested dimension of main window
    windowWidth = 800
    windowHeight = 600

    # Info for centering the window in the screen
    offsetLeft = int( (self.winfo_screenwidth() - windowWidth) / 2 )
    offsetTop  = int( (self.winfo_screenheight() - windowHeight) / 2 )

    # Positions the window in the center of the screen
    self.geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(windowWidth, windowHeight, offsetLeft, offsetTop))

    # set the window title
    self.title('Using the grid geometry manager, propagate(0) and tkraise() to show/hide frames') 

    # set a minimun window size, in order to preserve the container frame
    self.minsize(600, 400)

    # create a Frame widget in the main window, requested dimensions 600 x 400
    container = tk.Frame(self, width = 600, height = 400)
    # the frame should have a red background
    container.config(background='red')
    # the frame will go in row 0, column 0 of the grid in the windows
    container.grid(row=0, column=0)

    # this frame will not auto-size to fit its contents
    # in other words, its dimensions will always honor the ones requested for its width and size
    container.grid_propagate(0)

    # the grid in the root window (self here) is stretchable
    self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
                    
    self.frames = {}
    
    # create the needed frame (WelcomeScreen frame and Login frame)
    for F in (WelcomeScreen, Login):
      # this is the frame "name"
      page_name = F.__name__
      # create the frame in the red container frame. This current window is the controller (responsible for showing hidding frames)
      frame = F(container, self)
      # add the created frame to our list of controlled frames
      self.frames[page_name] = frame

      # the created frame will gon in row 0, colum 0, of its parent (the red container frame)
      frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

    # the grid in red container frame should stretch
    container.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    container.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    # ask the controller (this window) to show the WelcomeScreen frame (and hide all the others in the list of controlled frames)
    self.show_frame('WelcomeScreen')
    
  def show_frame(self, page_name):
    # since the controlled frames were made to be of the same size,
    # raising a frame will make it apeear 'in front' of the others, hiding them
    frame = self.frames[page_name]
    frame.tkraise()
    
class WelcomeScreen(tk.Frame):

  # this WelcomeScreen frame has a parent and a controller
  def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    
    # we initialize the base Frame class with some standard arguments. we request specific width and height
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, width = 360, height = 360)
    
    # this frame will not auto-size to fit its contents
    # in other words, its dimensions will always honor the ones requested for its width and size
    self.grid_propagate(0)

    # add a label to this frame (in row 0, column 0)
    Label(self,text='WELCOME TO THE INTRIM REPORT',font=('Arial Bold',16)).grid(row=0, pady=20)

    # get the image to be used in the next label to be created
    render = PhotoImage(file='logo2.png')

    # add label with an image to this frame  (in row 1, column 0)
    img = Label(self, image=render)
    img.image = render
    img.grid(row=1, column=0)
    
    # add another label to this frame (in row 2, column 0)
    Label(self,text='Press the button to proceed',font=('Arial Bold',10)).grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, pady=10)

    # add an 'proceed to login screen'  button to this frame (in row 3, column 0)
    # when this button is pressed, the Login frame should be shown and the WelcomeScreen frame should be hidden
    Button = tk.Button(self,text='Sign In',font=('Arial Bold',16),command=lambda: controller.show_frame('Login'))
    Button.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20,pady=20)

    # the grid in this frame should stretch
    self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

class Login(tk.Frame):

  # this Login frame has a parent and a controller
  def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    # we initialize the base Frame class with some standard arguments. we request specific width and height
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, width = 360, height = 360)
    
    # this frame will have a blue background
    self.config(background='blue')
    # this frame will not auto-size to fit its contents
    # in other words, its dimensions will always honor the ones requested for its width and size
    self.grid_propagate(0)

    # add a label to this frame (in row 0, column 0)
    Label(self,text='LOGIN SCREEN',font=('Arial Bold',16)).grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, columnspan=3)

    # add a label to this frame (in row 1, column 0)
    Label(self,text='Username',font=('Arial',12)).grid(row=1,column=0, padx=5, sticky='w')
    # add a label to this frame (in row 2, column 0)
    Label(self,text='Password',font=('Arial',12)).grid(row=2,column=0, padx=5, sticky='w')
    # add an Entry widget to this frame
    user = Entry(self)
    # the Entry widget will go in row 1, column 1, will span for 2 columns and will stretch left and right
    user.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=5, pady=5,columnspan=2,sticky='we')
    # add another Entry widget to this frame
    pwd = Entry(self)
    # the Entry widget go in row 2, column 1, will span for 2 columns and will stretch left and right
    pwd.grid(row=2,column=1,padx=5, pady=5,columnspan=2,sticky='we')
    
    # add a button to this frame
    # when this button is pressed, the checkLogin() function should be called with the stated parameters
    Button = tk.Button(self,text='LOGIN',command=lambda:checkLogin(str(user.get()),str(pwd.get())))
    # the button widget will go in row 3, column 2 and will stick to the rigth side of the grid cell
    Button.grid(row=3,column=2,columnspan=3,padx=5, pady=5, sticky='e')
    
    # add a button to this frame
    # when this button is pressed, the WelcomeScreen frame should be shown and the Login frame should be hidden
    Button = tk.Button(self,text='CANCEL',command=lambda: controller.show_frame('WelcomeScreen'))
    # the button widget will go in row 3, column 0 and will stick to the left of the grid cell
    Button.grid(row=3,column=0,columnspan=3,padx=5, pady=5,sticky='w')

    # the grid in this frame should stretch
    self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = InterimMain()
    app.mainloop()
```

The second solution is to let the controlled frames resize themselves at will, to fit their contents, and use another way to hide/show the controlled frames:

> **.grid_remove()**
> This method is like .grid_forget(), but its grid options are remembered, so if you .grid() it
> again, it will use the same grid configuration options.

So, `.grid_remove()` is used on a widget inside of a grid to make the widget invisible. Later, `.grid()` is used on the widget to make it reappear in the grid.
You just call `.grid()` with no parameters. It's enough to make the widget reappear as it was before `.grid_remove()` was used.

The code below uses this solution with `.grid_remove()` and `.grid()` to hide/show frames.
Note: I'm usig Python 3.9.1

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font as tkfont  # python 3
from tkinter.ttk import *

class InterimMain(tk.Tk):

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    # Requested dimension of main window
    windowWidth = 800
    windowHeight = 600

    # Info for centering the window in the screen
    offsetLeft = int( (self.winfo_screenwidth() - windowWidth) / 2 )
    offsetTop  = int( (self.winfo_screenheight() - windowHeight) / 2 )

    # Positions the window in the center of the screen
    self.geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(windowWidth, windowHeight, offsetLeft, offsetTop))

    # set the window title
    self.title('Using the grid geometry manager, .grid_remove() and .grid() to hide/show frames') 

    # create a Frame widget in the main window, requested dimensions 600 x 400
    container = tk.Frame(self,width=600, height= 400)
    # the frame should have a red background
    container.config(background="red")
    # the frame will go in row 0, column 0 of the grid in the windows
    container.grid(row=0, column=0)

    # set a minimun window size, in order to preserve the container frame
    self.minsize(windowWidth, windowHeight)
    
    # the grid in the root window (self here) is stretchable
    self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
                    
    #container.place(relx = 0.5,rely=0.5,anchor='c')
    #w = WelcomeScreen(controller)
    #l =Login(controller)
    
    self.frames = {}
    
    # create the needed frame (WelcomeScreen frame and Login frame)
    for F in (WelcomeScreen, Login):
      # this is the frame "name"
      page_name = F.__name__
      # create the frame in the main window
      frame = F(self)
      # add the created frame to our list of controlled frames
      self.frames[page_name] = frame

      # the created frame will gon in row 0, colum 0, of its parent (the red container frame)
      frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
      
    # ask the controller (this window) to show the WelcomeScreen frame (and hide all the others in the list of controlled frames)
    self.show_frame("WelcomeScreen")
    
  def show_frame(self, page_name):
    # hide all frames
    for aFrame in self.frames:
      # this will make the widget invisible, but its grid options will be remembered
      self.frames[aFrame].grid_remove()
    
    # show the requested frame
    # calling .grid() on a widget that was grid_remove()'d will restore its grid options and make it visible again
    self.frames[page_name].grid()

class WelcomeScreen(tk.Frame):

  # this WelcomeScreen frame has same widget as parent and controller
  def __init__(self, controller):

    # we initialize the base Frame class with no special arguments
    # we do not request width and height for the frame. They would not be honored,
    # since the frame will resize itself to fit
    # the widgets indside of it, due its grid geometry manager
    tk.Frame.__init__(self)
  
    # add a label to this frame (in row 0, column 0)
    Label(self,text="WELCOME TO THE INTRIM REPORT",font=("Arial Bold",16)).grid(row=0, column=0,pady=20)

    # get the image to be used in the next label to be created
    render = PhotoImage(file='logo2.png')
    
    # add label with an image to this frame  (in row 1, column 0)
    img = Label(self, image=render)
    img.image = render
    img.grid(row=1, column=0)
    
    # add another label to this frame (in row 2, column 0)
    Label(self,text="Press the button to proceed",font=("Arial Bold",10)).grid(padx=5,row=2,column=0,pady=10)

    # add an 'proceed to login screen'  button to this frame (in row 3, column 0)
    # when this button is pressed, the Login frame should be shown and the WelcomeScreen frame should be hidden
    Button = tk.Button(self,text="Sign In",font=("Arial Bold",16),command=lambda: controller.show_frame("Login"))
    Button.grid(row=3,column=0,padx=20,pady=20)

class Login(tk.Frame):

  # this WelcomeScreen frame has same widget as parent and controller
  def __init__(self,controller):

    # we initialize the base Frame class with no special arguments
    # we do not request width and height for the frame. They would not be honored,
    # since the frame will resize itself to fit
    # the widgets indside of it, due its grid geometry manager
    tk.Frame.__init__(self)
    
    # this frame will have a blue background
    self.config(background="blue")

    # add a label to this frame (in row 0, column 0)
    Label(self,text="LOGIN SCREEN",font=("Arial Bold",16)).grid(row=0,column=0, padx=5, pady=10,columnspan=3)

    # add a label to this frame (in row 1, column 0)
    Label(self,text="Username",font=("Arial",12)).grid(row=1,column=0, padx=5, sticky='w')
    # add a label to this frame (in row 2, column 0)
    Label(self,text="Password",font=("Arial",12)).grid(row=2,column=0, padx=5, sticky='w')
    # add an Entry widget to this frame
    user = Entry(self)
    # the Entry widget will go in row 1, column 1, will span for 2 columns and will stretch left and right
    user.grid(row=1,column=1, padx=5, pady=5,columnspan=2,sticky='we')
    # add another Entry widget to this frame
    pwd = Entry(self)
    # the Entry widget go in row 2, column 1, will span for 2 columns and will stretch left and right
    pwd.grid(row=2,column=1, padx=5, pady=5,columnspan=2,sticky='we')
    
    # add a button to this frame
    # when this button is pressed, the checkLogin() function should be called with the stated parameters
    Button = tk.Button(self,text="LOGIN",command=lambda:checkLogin(str(user.get()),str(pwd.get())))
    # the button widget will go in row 3, column 2 and will stick to the rigth side of the grid cell
    Button.grid(row=3,column=2,columnspan=3, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='e')

    # add a button to this frame
    # when this button is pressed, the WelcomeScreen frame should be shown and the Login frame should be hidden
    Button = tk.Button(self,text="CANCEL",command=lambda: controller.show_frame('WelcomeScreen'))
    # the button widget will go in row 3, column 0 and will stick to the left of the grid cell
    Button.grid(row=3,column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='w')
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = InterimMain()
    app.mainloop()
```